# How to rename text with jQuery

Tags: jquery, wordpress

On a page, I have a portfolio with 3 categories, there is a **SHOW ALL** which appears all the photos of the portfolio.I would like to translate **SHOW ALL** with jQuery the path of the element is

```
.qodef-pl-filter-holder ul li.qodef-pl-current span
```

I tried to add custom JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
        var content=“ΟΛΑ“;
    $(“.qodef-pl-filter-holder ul li.qodef-pl-current span”).html(content);
        
});
```

This replaced the content but only when I was refreshing the page.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you actually have fancy quotes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your code but it work in snippet

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
    var content = 'ΟΛΑ';
    $('.qodef-pl-filter-holder ul li.qodef-pl-current span').html(content);   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="qodef-pl-filter-holder">
  <ul>
    <li class="qodef-pl-current"><span>Show All</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @tonebtr12 Edit your first post and post all your code plz.